# Non-localized text in es.SO and pt.SO

Tags: bug, profile-page, localization

**Update**: Thank you for your direction. I've posted it on [es.MSO](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2958/68514) and [pt.MSO](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6650/98850).

---

Although I give only one screenshot, this part reads *Rarest badges* on **both** Spanish SO and Portuguese SO. Maybe it should be localized?

> EN: (The) Rarest badges
>   ES: (Las) Insignias más raras
>   PT: (Os) Emblemas mais raros

Plus the "No badges" (in the "Gold" section) there.

> EN: No badges
>   ES: Sin insignias
>   PT: <sub>(No sample translation because I don't know Portuguese)</sub>

[image]
<sup>click to enlarge</sup>

---

Please leave a comment if you think it's better for this post to be posted to es.MSO and pt.MSO.

Comment: Aren't these issues for the relevant sites rather than MSE? I'd say you should be posting there.

Comment: @ChrisF I thought a question about two or more sites is on-topic here. Also, I can speak neither Spanish nor Portuguese (despite the fact that I know a few words in both). I don't think a full English post will be welcomed there.

Comment: True, but looking at it as "Text not translated on Spanish SO" and "Text not translated on Portuguese SO" each problem only affects one site. I know that's splitting hairs, but I would have thought you'd get a better response - i.e. the text being translated - if you post where the problem actually is.

Comment: @ChrisF I bet you wouldn't have said that if ru.SO and jp.SO were affected, too. Anyway, I've posted here and I don't want to cross-post, which requires me to create accounts there.

Comment: Nope. The problem is not network wide.

Comment: Translation of the localized sites lies on the shoulders of users who have access to the transifex DB. This could be a Network wide issue if and only if these strings are not available to translate at all, i.e. there are no strings in DB, or translation is not used. In this case the site engine should be improved (fixed).

Comment: @alexolut So what's your opinion about my posting this Q?

Comment: @iDebug these strings already translated for ruSO, so this is site specific issue, and should be posted on related metas. You can post it in English there, local users could translate it.

Comment: @iDebug yes, I think it could be better solution.